# Idea to download images in android

Tags: android, image

I'm making an android app, here the images are getting from Cloud, is it good idea to download images and save it & use it further. Or download images every-time user uses the app, what idea you prefer is the best?

Because downloading images always is slow & its bad i know but at some point if the images are updated then how to get to know about it?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely cache your downloaded files!
Do it in your internal app directory where only you do have access to (or otherwise external storage, thats still ok).
Bandwidth and connections are always expensive and should kept low as much as possible.

So your user can see images fast even on a bad connection and your app doesn't waste his valuable bandwidth of a users data plan.

Maybe this could also help you:

https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy on yourself and use something like [Android Smart Image View](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/). It takes care of loading and caching, and it's just about a drop-in replacement for Android's ImageView. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is another alternative, more configurable, but not as quick to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I used https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
but I think you not want only download and cache.
these no trick ,if you want check weather the image update or not,  you can add metadata for image, just like md5 .

in html and browser, you can set expires header for a image:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098185/how-do-i-add-an-expiration-date-to-an-img-tag)
but in android app, you control all yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading images and saving them is probably the best way to do it because you don't want to download the same images over and over. If the images are updated you can delete the older one and download the new ones. Just make sure you don't download/save a million images. Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It has a built-in cache on sdcard/external sd.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading images from the net for display, with possible requirement of caching is a very common problem that many people have solved, you can try these solutions to see which fits you:

1. **Ion** (https://github.com/koush/ion) - very flexible and feature complete, plus it can download more than images but JSON, Strings, Files, and Java types as well. The part that I really like about this is that it can automatically cancel operations when the calling Activity finishes, so users don't waste time & bandwidth downloading images that will no longer be displayed
2. **Universal Image Loader** (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) - equally capable for most use cases but for downloading/caching images only